# Typechecking failure in code using Type Families

Tags: haskell, type-families

I have module Data.FastSet, where this typeclass is defined:

```
    {-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

    class HasFastSet elt where
      type FastSet elt :: *
      empty :: FastSet elt
      fromList :: [elt] -> FastSet elt
      member :: elt -> FastSet elt -> Bool
      eq :: FastSet elt -> FastSet elt -> Bool
      insert :: elt -> FastSet elt -> FastSet elt
      union :: FastSet elt -> FastSet elt -> FastSet elt
      filter :: (elt -> Bool) -> FastSet elt -> FastSet elt
```

along with a couple of instances. Then, in some other module, I'm trying to use it:

```
    {-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes, TypeFamilies, ScopedTypeVariables #-}
    import qualified Data.FastSet as FS

    data StaticInfo elt = StaticInfo { matchesEmpty :: Bool,
                                       starters :: FS.FastSet elt }


    sequentialCompose :: forall m elt. (Monad m, FS.HasFastSet elt) =>
    m (StaticInfo elt) -> m (StaticInfo elt) -> m (StaticInfo elt)
    sequentialCompose si1 si2 = do 
      StaticInfo me1 st1 <- si1
      case me1 of
        False -> si1
        True  -> do
                   StaticInfo me2 st2 <- si2
                   let together = FS.union st1 st2 :: FS.FastSet elt
                   return (StaticInfo me2 together)
```

As you see, I've tried to use ScopedTypeVariables extension to tell typechecker that result of union of two sets has the same type as sets themselves. When I try to compile this, it gives me type error (and it's the same regardless of my attempt to give explicit type to `together` variable:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘FS.FastSet elt’
            with actual type ‘FS.FastSet elt1’
NB: ‘FS.FastSet’ is a type function, and may not be injective
The type variable ‘elt1’ is ambiguous
Relevant bindings include
  together :: FS.FastSet elt
    (bound at /home/olympia/concurrency-talk/chat-benchmark/src/Text/Parsing/StaticInfo.hs:24:20)
  st2 :: FS.FastSet elt
    (bound at /home/olympia/concurrency-talk/chat-benchmark/src/Text/Parsing/StaticInfo.hs:23:31)
  st1 :: FS.FastSet elt
    (bound at /home/olympia/concurrency-talk/chat-benchmark/src/Text/Parsing/StaticInfo.hs:19:18)
  si2 :: m (StaticInfo elt)
    (bound at /home/olympia/concurrency-talk/chat-benchmark/src/Text/Parsing/StaticInfo.hs:18:23)
  si1 :: m (StaticInfo elt)
    (bound at /home/olympia/concurrency-talk/chat-benchmark/src/Text/Parsing/StaticInfo.hs:18:19)
  sequentialCompose :: m (StaticInfo elt)
                       -> m (StaticInfo elt) -> m (StaticInfo elt)
    (bound at /home/olympia/concurrency-talk/chat-benchmark/src/Text/Parsing/StaticInfo.hs:18:1)
In the expression: FS.union st1 st2 :: FS.FastSet elt
In an equation for ‘together’:
    together = FS.union st1 st2 :: FS.FastSet elt
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the problem is that a `elt -> FS.FastSet elt` is not *injective* (meaning there might be `elt` and `elt'` with the same `FS.FastSet elt ~ FS.FastSet elt'` - right now you cannot do much here but injective type-families are on their way ;)

Comment: I *think* you can come up with something working if you change your operations to `union :: elt -> elt -> elt` instead

Comment: I suspect `FastSet` should better be an associated `data` family, rather than type family. These _are_ injective.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you are somewhat misusing associated types. It should not be the case that practically every argument of your methods is a type family.

The class definition readily allows an instance like:

```
instance HasFastSet Int where
    type FastSet Int = Bool
    -- ...
```

And now, for that instance, `union :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool` which GHC is going to have a hard time knowing that's the `Int` instance's `union`, especially because, as the error message states, you could have an instance for `Char` with `type FastSet Char :: Bool`.

So what's happening in your code is when you are using `union`, it doesn't know what `union` to use.  Because type families are not injective, it's irrelevant that the parameters have type `FastSet elt` because `FastSet elt ~ FastSet elt1` is possible.  Similarly, the class context is also irrelevant.  At that use of `union` GHC doesn't care what the class constraints on the function as a whole are, and even if it did you could just be missing a constraint, so the constraints you provided won't resolve the issue.

A more normal usage of associated types would be more like having an element type associated to a class parameterized by a collection type, something like, then you get type family instances like `type Elem [Int] = Int` and the methods are resolvable without having to guess the type family instance.  You could switch to data families, but I think that you would be better off reconsidering your approach entirely.